# Google auth library payload types in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I am new in `typescript`. I use `google auth library` many time in `javascript`. But I am facing problem when I am trying to use it in my `typescript` project. Here I am using common js module (`Nestjs`)

Here is my code example-

```
import { OAuth2Client } from "google-auth-library";
const client = new OAuth2Client(process.env.GOOGLE_ID);

async google({ idToken }: GoogleInput): Promise < RegisterSuccess > {
    const clientId = process.env.GGOOGLE_ID;
    const { payload } = await client.verifyIdToken({ idToken: idToken, audience: clientId });
    console.log(payload);
    return {
        success: true,
        message: "Authentication successfull!",
    }
}
```

Here in `payload` I get name, given_name, family_name, email and many field. Now I have to define type of this `payload`. I already tried.

```
export type Payload = {
    name: string;
    given_name: string;
    family_name: string;
    email: string;
    picture: string;
    iss: string;
    sub: string;
}
```

and I try it in may way-

```
const { payload }: {Payload} = await client.verifyIdToken({ idToken: idToken, audience: clientId });

const { payload }: Payload = await client.verifyIdToken({ idToken: idToken, audience: clientId });

const { payload: Payload } = await client.verifyIdToken({ idToken: idToken, audience: clientId });
```

None of this way working. I am getting same error every time-

```
Property 'payload' is private and only accessible within class 'LoginTicket'
```

Here I also try to use `LoginTicket` from `auth library`.

```
import { OAuth2Client, LoginTicket } from "google-auth-library";

const { payload: LoginTicket } = await client.verifyIdToken({ idToken: idToken, audience: clientId });

const { payload}: LoginTicket = await client.verifyIdToken({ idToken: idToken, audience: clientId });

const { payload}: { LoginTicket } = await client.verifyIdToken({ idToken: idToken, audience: clientId });
```

This also are not working. Then How can I define this `payload`. Please help me anyone, please.

Answer (score 0):

The library provides the interface called `TokenPayload`. Not sure why you still need to define a new type.

Try like below

```js
import { OAuth2Client, TokenPayload } from 'google-auth-library';

const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({ idToken, audience: clientId });
const payload = ticket.getPayload();
```